# How do I enable antialiasing in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, antialiasing, post-processing

I am interested in adding antialiasing to my project in Unity. I read that to achieve this you must import Post Processing Stack. I have downloaded it from the asset store but i cant figure out how to use it. There are also settings in: Menu -> Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality, but they seem to not work.

What exactly do i have to do?

Comment: Sorry if a simply reply with a link, but...does this help? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Stack-SetUp.html

Comment: If you're using a modern version of unity, you can just enable it in the [Quality Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html)

Comment: 8x Multi Sampling in Quality Settings looks still aliased. Is there something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the PostProcessing Stack add a PostProcessingBehaviour component to your camera. Then, in the project window, create a PostProcessingProfile using right click and context menu.
Then, drag the newly created profile into a slot in the Behaviour component.

The profile has its own editor and changes can be made interactively.

I have a feeling antialiasing only worked if the camera rendering mode was set to deferred but that might not be true.

Good luck

Comment: What assets do I have to import for this?

Comment: PostProcessing Stack